# What is the meaning of the phrasal verb "get for" in this sentence?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

When I was watching a YouTube video about the historic Trump-Kim summit in Singapore, I noticed a comment that says

> Not a big fan of trump, but he **gets for** this one, nice job!

Is this expression correct? If so, what does it mean ? and Is it very common?

Comment: gets a thumbs up for xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube comments represent their own medium, and are not a place to expect to see standard English. The key to understanding the comment is that it is not *gets for*, it is *gets  for*.

Emoji are not merely decorative, nor are they intended to have a single interpretation. They can convey meaning by indicating emotion or tone or by providing a certain context to something, but like any pictogram they can represent a word or phrase, either literal or in an expression (e.g.  *drop*). They can be a reference to something (cf. [Trump-Kim summit emoji](https://techcrunch.com/2018/06/11/twitter-emoji-trump-kim-summit-north-korea/)), or to a homophone (*having a ⚾*).

But here, it is simply the common name for the symbol itself that the author is inserting; the hand is making a [thumbs-up](https://emojipedia.org/thumbs-up-sign/) gesture, indicating approval, and so the comment should be read as

> [I'm] not a big fan of Trump, but he gets a thumbs-up for this one, nice job!